# ModelState.IsValid is false because CreatedBy field is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an entity with, amongst others, the fields: `CreatedBy`, `CreatedAt`, `ChangedAt`

Now in the view, I do not want the user to fill these fields.
My approach was to fill them on the HTTP POST Action, before `ModelState.IsValid` check is made and before saving the data to the database.

However, `ModelState.IsValid` keeps returning false no matter what. What is the right way to implement this? Should I take the validation (`ModelState.IsValid`) from the POST action?

Comment: What's inside `ModelState.Errors`?

Comment: Add a breakpoint on `ModelState.IsValid` and check `ModelState.Errors`.

Comment: Have you tried, filling them on the Page load instead of the POST? If you create an item you can simply set Datetime.Now and the current User. The items will be put into the (hidden)fields and should be available on your Http POST

Comment: @Serv then a user can just change the hidden field, so it seems like someone else created the item.

Comment: Yea, having the fields hidden is not what I want for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many projects like to separate the *View Model* from the *Domain Model*. This allows you to create a View-Model class specifically tailored for the data you want to render and/or receive in a certain action while keeping the domain model correct/consistent.

In your View-Model class you would either not define any such property as the created date (since it is not supposed to be posted but is determined in the action). Or if you use one and the same View-Model for rendering *and* posting, and you want to render the date, you can make the date nullable (see Alexey's answer) on the View-Model while keeping it mandatory on the domain model.

Comment: Great. ViewModel implementation is the perfect solution! Thanks chiccodoro.

Answer (score 3):

One problem, many solutions (from best to worst, in my opinion).

**First solution**

The best way would be to use a ViewModel (a class containing only the fields which must be edited by user and / or validated).

In this case, the CreatedBy, CreatedAt, ChangedAt fields would not appear in your ViewModel class.

**Second solution**

If you don't want ViewModel, you can put the "not mutable by user" fields as hidden fields in your view

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CreatedAt)
```

of course, hidden fields can be changed by user, so it's always an open door to unwanted datas...

**Third solution**

Clean `ModelState` from undesired errors before checking if it's valid (should become really boring if you've many fields concerned).

```
if (ModelState.ContainsKey("CreatedAt")) {
  ModelState["CreatedAt"].Errors.Clear();
}

//then test for ModelState.IsValid()
```

**Other solutions**

WhiteList, BlackList for model binding, or... anything I forgot !

Answer (score 1):

DateTime is not nullable. If you want to keep those fields as null during model binding, if there is no values for them use:

`Nullable<DateTime>`

or shortcut:

```
DateTime?
```